# Download to excel using MVC is not working in Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, model-view-controller

I need to give download option in MVC for that i have returned one function its generate the excel and downloaded in local but after deployed in server its redirecting but generate the excel file.

My Codes

Views

```
<a href="/Report/StockOnHandToExcel" style="font-weight: bold" >Export To Excel</a>
```

Controller

```
public void StockOnHandToExcel()
   {
        try
        {
            var dt = DataTableClass.ToDataTable(_report.StockOnHandExcelList());
            var stream = ExcelUtility.GetExcel(dt);

            var filename = "StockOnHand.xlsx";
            var contenttype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = contenttype;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandlerClass.LogMessage(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the problem is.

Comment: While user clicking the a tag the excel is generated and downloaded working fine in local host but when i deployed into the server excel is not download i dont know what is the problem

Comment: Did you try using the browser Developer tools or something like Fiddler to monitor the response?  If there was an error it should be in your application logs (assuming your errorHandlerClass is implemented)

Comment: Try with Retrun File() like this :  return File(excelBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName)

Comment: What is ExcelUtility.GetExcel? Does it requires the excel to be installed? is the Excel installed on server?

Comment: You must turn your `void` into a `ActionResult`, then as a result give the excel content.

Comment: This doesnt look like a MVC code at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public FileResult StockOnHandToExcel()
        {
            try
            {
                var dt = DataTableClass.ToDataTable(_report.StockOnHandExcelList());
                var stream = ExcelUtility.GetExcel(dt);
                int length = (int)stream.Length;
                byte[] data = new byte[length];
                stream.Position = 0;
                stream.Read(data, 0, length);
                var fileStream = new MemoryStream(data);
                return File(fileStream, "application/ms-excel", "StockOnHand.xls");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandlerClass.LogMessage(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

//it may be work！